# Trouble processing file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am new to python and am attempting to read a text file.

The file is of the below format.
Note the `\r` represents carriage return. `\n` represents a new line.

Would someone tell me what is the best approach to get this file read? I am attempting to read the file and do some other manipulation to each line of data that was read in then write to a new file. I seem to be making a mistake on the line with 5 fields.

```
field1|field2|field3\r\n
field1|field2|field3\r\n
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5\r\n
\r\n
\r
string 1\r
\r\n
\r
string 2\r
\r\n
\r
string 3\r
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5\r\n
\r\n
\r
string 1\r
\r\n
\r
string 2\r
\r\n
\r
string 3\r
```

Here is the actual code

```
with open('myFile.txt','r') as f:
    line = f.readlines(1);
    while line:
        line = f.readlines(1)    
        if not line:
            print('List is empty')
            continue
        else:
            numofPipes = line[0].count('|')

        if numofPipes == 95:
            newOutput = line[0].rstrip('\r').rstrip('\n') + '|||||||||^'
            print(newOutput)
        elif numofPipes == 103:
            newOutput = line[0].rstrip('\r').rstrip('\n') + '|'       
            # finish inserting code to continue to read lines until condition met
            reportText = f.realines(1)
            print(newOutput)
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on what exactly you want to do to this file, and the code you're currently using?

Comment: Can you show the code you're trying? What's going wrong with it? What do you expect the results to be, and what are you getting instead? Just seeing the contents of the file isn't enough for us to know what you want to do with it.

Comment: According to what you are sharing with us we can only say that you should loop through the lines of the file, process each one and then write it to a new file...

Comment: I think my primary issue is with the carriage return.  The overall goal is to read the file and consolidate the combine the bad data into the preceding record. The bad data (not with a record is for the preceeding record). String 1, String 2, and String 3 should all be on the previous record so they all print on the same line in the new file.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a file using `f = open("example.txt","w+")`
The option "w" means write, and "+" means that it will create a new file if it doesn't exist, you can also use "r" to read or "a" to append

To write in that file, you can use `f.write()`, just like a print statement

To read the whole file you can use `f.readlines()`

To read the file partially you can use `f.read(bytes)`, where "bytes" is number of bytes to be read from the opened file

To check the position in the file you're in you can use `f.tell()`

To change the position, use `f.seek(offset[, from])` the "offset" argument indicates the number of bytes to be moved. The "from" argument specifies the reference position from where the bytes are to be moved

To rename the file, you can use `os.rename("originalName.txt", "newName.txt")`, (to do that you'll need to `import os`)

Finally, you can remove the file using `os.remove("fileName.txt")`, (again, you'll need to `import os`)

That's it for files in python

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to extract from the file and how the data will be transformed. A typical line-based processing loop would look like this:

```
with open('myfile') as file:
  for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if line:
      fields = line.split('|')
      # Do something with the fields
      print(fields)
```